# date format not applying in kendo hierarchy grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using:

```
columns.Bound(j => j.sDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}', kendo.parseDate(sDate)) #").Title("sDate");
```

But geiing following error,

error:
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid template.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code:

```
   columns.Bound(j => j.sDate).ClientTemplate("\\#= kendo.format('{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}',  
   kendo.parseDate(sDate)) \\#").Title("sDate");
```

---

Add in web.config file.

```
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" targetFramework="4.5"   
  encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,  
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```